# c# Socket DuplicateAndClose

Tags: c#, tcp

I am writing my Socket using TCP/IP protocol and I have a simple question. What does Socket.DuplicateAndClose() do? And when to use it?

Comment: Go google, and search for this method in C#. In S.O. we try to help to solve problems, no questions on what X thing do, when you have google. Try to do the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour to do good questions

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask such questions..You could google this method and find many websites that give a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the Socket constructor multiple times with the same byte array as the argument for each call, you will create multiple managed Socket instances with the same underlying socket. This practice is strongly discouraged.